# Toshiba C55-B5298 - Memory & Hard Drive Upgrade

Tags: memory, ssd, toshiba-laptop

I have this Toshibha laptop with 4GB RAM and Windows 10 home edition. The laptop is terribly slow. I'm not sure if I can upgrade the RAM and hard drive to SSD. I would really appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Hello. What kind of recommendations are you looking for? I've never used or seen this laptop before but searching revealed [this Cruical webpage](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-c55-b5298) which details RAM and SSD upgrades on this laptop - is it a Satellite model? Bear in mind that I think this webpage exists to promote the products listed!

Comment: [Support page here](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200008397), download the specifications PDF, it says memory is not user upgradeable. You can however install a 7200 rpm sata hard drive to  improve performance, or an SSD.

Comment: The processor is the killer in that system, it s a [Celeron N2830](http://ark.intel.com/products/81071/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2830-1M-Cache-up-to-2_41-GHz), a turd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=4005876&isFromTOCLink=false) the computer has a standard 500GS SATA hard drive, so you can almost certainly upgrade this to an SSD, and, for regular desktop applications this will make a huge difference.

As @Moab pointed out the processor on this system is a dog - however if you are only using it for basic web browsing, documents, spreadsheets and similar, swapping the hard disk for an SSD should make a huge difference.

Upgrading the RAM from 4 gigs to 8 gigs is probably not worthwhile - any system which is doing enough heavy lifting to justify more then 4 gigs of RAM needs a much better CPU.    (In general, this system is pretty old and not worth throwing money at).

Another thing to look at doing is to remove Windows and install a lightweight Linux distro - You will find the system a lot snappier as Linux uses less resources.